# Passing multiple files with whitespace to python script

Tags: linux, python, find

I have to convert a lot of .ai files to .svg, and I've found ai2svg tool. I've tried

```
for i in `find ./ -type f -name \*.ai`; do python ai2svg.py "$i"; done
```

But I get errors like

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Profile'
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "ai2svg.py", line 171, in 
>       inf = open (sys.argv[1])

When the filename is "Profile test.ai". Is there any way around it, except for removing all whitespace in names from .ai files beforehand?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
find . -type f -name \*.ai -exec python ai2svg.py {} \;
```

If `ai2svg.py` works with multiple files (like most *nix tools), you can do this to run the command the minimum amount of times:

```
find . -type f -name \*.ai -exec python ai2svg.py {} +
```

If you only care about files in the current directory you can use the standard loop for this:

```
for file in *.ai
do
    python ai2svg.py "$file"
done
```

Comment: I've found out about "find ./ -type f -name \*.ai -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do python ai2svg.py "$file"; done" too. Is it true that for loops with find are a bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it is the following:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.ai' -print0 | while read -d '' -r file; do python ai2svg.py "$file"; done
```

Notice `-print0` option of `find` which together with `-d ''` in `read` takes care of any whitespace characters in the filenames, including newlines and tabs.

Comment: That's not POSIX compatible, and using the NUL separator is only necessary if you want to do something more complicated than `-exec` on the filename.